# Falta traducir las etiquetas obligatorias en ¿Qué es "Meta" y cómo funciona?

Tags: bug, traducciones, centro-de-ayuda

## Resumen

En https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta aparecen las etiquetas obligatorias en inglés pero actualmente se tienen etiquetas en español como las principales y las que están en inglés como sinónimos. Por consistencia, en el artículo de ayuda deberían estar en español.

El texto a traducir tiene formato de código.

## Fragmento de texto actual

> El texto se incluye tal cual se muestra en el artículo de ayuda.

Porque los sitios de meta-discusión son diferentes y sirven a multiplés  propósitos, algunas meta-etiquetas están bien e incluso son obligatorias. Cada pregunta en meta requieres incluir alguna de las siguientes etiquetas:

- `[support]`, que indica que es una solicitud de asistencia o soporte con alguna de las funciones del sitio.
- `[bug]`, denota un problema reproducible en el sitio que tú crees que es un error, mal funcionamiento, o error de programación.
- `[feature-request]`, para proponer una nueva función para el sitio, o solicitar que alguna función actual sea modificada.
- `[discussion]`, para preguntas que no tienen una claro respuesta o respuesta equivocada y son a menudo subjetivas. Si no es un bug, una solicitud de función es probablemente una discusión.

## Fragmento de texto sugerido

> Se corrigieron acentos y otros errores, mas no necesariamente todos.

Porque los sitios de meta-discusión son diferentes y sirven a múltiples propósitos, algunas meta-etiquetas están bien e incluso son obligatorias. Cada pregunta en meta requiere incluir alguna de las siguientes etiquetas:

- `[soporte]`, que indica que es una solicitud de asistencia o soporte con alguna de las funciones del sitio.
- `[bug]`, denota un problema reproducible en el sitio que tú crees que es un error, mal funcionamiento, o error de programación.
- `[característica-nueva]`, para proponer una nueva función para el sitio, o solicitar que alguna función actual sea modificada.
- `[discusión]`, para preguntas que no tienen una claro respuesta o respuesta equivocada y son a menudo subjetivas. Si no es un bug, una solicitud de función es probablemente una discusión.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

Después de algunos años, ya se han traducido.

- [Issue en github](https://github.com/g3rv4/help-pages/issues/39)
- [Pull Request con la sugerencia](https://github.com/g3rv4/help-pages/pull/40/files)

Aquí todo sobre el **[proceso de traducción de los artículos del centro de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4466/65107)**