# ¿Cómo puedo sugerir un arreglo a una traducción en el centro de ayuda?

Tags: soporte, traducciones, centro-de-ayuda

Encontré un artículo en [el centro de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/help) que tiene problemas ¿cómo puedo sugerir una nueva traducción o arreglar el texto que aparece ahí?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El proceso al día de hoy es el siguiente:

1. Abrir un issue en [el repositorio del centro de ayuda](https://github.com/g3rv4/help-pages) pidiendo que agregue el artículo en cuestión (si no existe)
2. Esperar a que suba el archivo al repositorio (le llega un e-mail a la persona que abrió el issue)
3. Crear un PR con la sugerencia de traducción
4. Yo hago el cambio en el centro de ayuda

Comment: Oh, veo que el repo ahora está en modo de lectura solamente :( Fue genial lo que montaste

Comment: querido! ya no trabajo más en SO, por lo que ya no puedo editar los artículos de ayuda a piacere :) gbianchi mencionó que al CM le gustó esta idea, pero ni idea de que van a hacer. Tendría que borrar mi respuesta y esperar que un mod/cm responda porque ahora es mentirosa.

Comment: Pues me sale de dentro agradecerte todo lo que has hecho y puse una publicación: [Gracias por tanto, g3rv4](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5101/83). ¡¡Muchas gracias por todo!!

Comment: aaahhh <3 <3 <3 <3