# ¿Para qué querría cerrar yo mi propia pregunta?

Tags: soporte, cierre-de-preguntas, centro-de-ayuda, privilegios

Recién llego a 250 puntos y me aparece el mensaje de que tengo como privilegio nuevo [ver y emitir votos para cerrar y reabrir mis propias preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes)... Creo que entiendo la teoría pero no la práctica.

Entendí perfecto que puede ser para cuando

> - Hiciste una pregunta que ya se había realizado previamente

-Claro, perdón, no la había visto! jaja

**Pero** me quedé atónito al leer:

> - Tu pregunta no está relacionada a la temática del sitio

En primer lugar, para qué la haría!!!... Pero supongamos que es algo que no sabía, me lo comentan, lo entiendo y lo comparto... Por qué no borrarla y listo?!

**Y además**, como frutilla del postre, me encuentro con:

> También puedes emitir votos de cierre o reapertura sobre tus propias preguntas.

-Alguien que me confirme por favor que fue un simple error al poner la palabra "También", porque sino no estoy entendiendo nada. ¿"También" aparte de qué? ¿Acaso no es eso lo que estaba leyendo arriba? (la otra parte del párrafo se entiende, que a los 3000 puedo votar por preguntas de otros). Si llegara a ser un error y por lo que veo [se puede corregir](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4466/193460), también recomendaría agregar al combo que no esté 2 veces el mismo título "¿Qué es una pregunta cerrada?". Yo honestamente no sabría qué proponer.

Comment: Muchas veces nos encontramos con la necesidad de hacer alguna pregunta que *creemos* encaja con la temática del sitio, pero sucede que no es así, por lo cual si bien podemos eliminarla directamente, otras veces preferimos que sea la comunidad que opine si la misma debe ser cerrada o no. No es un error entonces, ya que de esta forma puedes compartir la opinión de la comunidad en caso de cierre. Elaborar una pregunta / respuesta requiere tiempo y dedicación. La acción de borrarla desmerece todo ese esfuerzo. Siempre puedes editarla para ajustar lo necesario y proponer su reapertura. Saludos

Comment: Gracias @MauricioContreras. Entiendo tu punto. Para serte sincero, me parece poco factible. Yo personalmente no lo tomaría como desmerecer el esfuerzo si decido que una pregunta mía no debería estar, pero no tengo experiencia haciendo preguntas... La última parte de tu comentario sí me parece un poco entreverada: ¿Para qué eligiría yo cerrar mi propia pregunta, editarla y reabrirla... en vez de editarla y listo?

Comment: Puedes cerrar para evitar que se agreguen respuestas o apliquen votos negativos mientras realizas cambios. Ya que terminaste la edición y la pregunta es apta, la reabres. Por ejemplo, a veces elimino una de mis respuestas porque hubo algún error o no entendí la pregunta; hago las ediciones y después la recupero.