# Error de escritura en el artículo sobre preguntas cerradas del Centro de Ayuda

Tags: bug, estado-completado, centro-de-ayuda

estaba leyendo esta página sobre preguntas cerradas https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions y detecte un error de escritura

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error está marcado, deberia decir "si tu pregunta se ha puesto en espera", El error aparece en el primer parrafo de la pagina

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo puedo sugerir un arreglo a una traducción en el centro de ayuda?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4466/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-sugerir-un-arreglo-a-una-traducci%c3%b3n-en-el-centro-de-ayuda)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Listo, fue corregido!

Y como tengo que poner 30 caracteres, les mando un feliz año nuevo...

Comment: creo que tambien deberia decir "recibirás un feedback privado", actualmente está escrito como "recibirás feedback privado", falta el "un", está igualmente en la última oración del primer párrafo

Comment: mmmm.. ahi dudo porque lo que dice se lee correctamente... la palabra un no me suena que falte... no recibe un mensaje personal, recibe un cartel en la pregunta...