# Textos de etiquetas no traducidas

Tags: soporte, estado-completado, traducciones, centro-de-ayuda

Iba a escribir sobre que una frase y las etiquetas en [¿Qué es "meta" y cómo funciona?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) estaban en inglés, cuando se me han sugerido preguntas similares.

En concreto [Falta traducir las etiquetas obligatorias en ¿Qué es “Meta” y cómo funciona?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1515/falta-traducir-las-etiquetas-obligatorias-en-qu%C3%A9-es-meta-y-c%C3%B3mo-funciona) es prácticamente igual a la que yo iba a poner, y veo que en la única respuesta que tiene pone `estado completado`, pero los nombres de las etiquetas siguen en inglés:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También en una frase de la misma página algo más arriba pone (si lo buscáis está en en negrita):

> Sobre preguntas etiquetadas [feature-request](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/caracter%C3%ADstica-nueva?tab=Newest), votar indica acuerdo
> o desacuerdo

Creo que lo correcto sería poner `característica-nueva` en vez de `feature-request`.

Comment: Qué raro, porque la merge request al repo de g3rv4 se aprobó y solía ser automático que pasara a aparecer. Mirando en wayback machine, en agosto de 2020 (un mes después de la MR) [seguía viéndose en inglés](http://web.archive.org/web/20200801000000*/https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es que se tradujese el texto de ayuda de lo que hace la etiqueta, pero los nombres en esa página no. Pero hablo sin conocimiento ya que no sé como funciona ni cómo estaba en su momento, @fedorqui.

Comment: La pull request sí cambiaba el nombre de las etiquetas en el artículo: https://github.com/g3rv4/help-pages/pull/40/files